# Marker Line Symbol with Character Marker Symbols gets grayed when published to map service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, map-service, arcgis-10.3

After publishing as Map Service character marker symbols become grayed even if their colour is black in definition. This odd behaviour happens in ArcMap 10.2.2 and ArcMap 10.3.

Are there are any issues registered in ESRI KB regarding this problem? I could not find a similar one.

EDIT: Tried to play with different symbols and it seems that text colour is black only for "thicker" characters or fully filled ones. For example Arial letters turns into gray but Arial Black (thicker font) letters are black. This could be anti-aliasing related issue.

EDIT2: Played with Text Anti-Aliasing options when Publishing Parameters dialogue. Gray with options Force and Normal, black only with None. But other texts look ugly with option None... What workaround is possible here?..

[image: Differences in ArcMap compared vs Map Service]

The line symbol definition is shown below, I don't see any magic here.
[image: Marker Line Symbol definition in ArcMap]